# Working with REST, SQL, foreign keys, and nested resources

Tags: sql, rest, nested, foreign-keys

I'm struggling to understand how to handle nested resources in REST.

For example, if I have a table called cities, and another table called companies that has a foreign key constraint(a company exists in a city), then when someone GETs a city, should I also send a list of all companies in that city? If so, if they do a PUT on a specific city(cities/55) and they have the nested collection of companies present, do I also update the nested companies?

Or how about a delete? Do I cascade delete all companies in a city, or just change the city they are in to a null value temporarily...

At a certain point, the SQL I am doing on the nested resources could get pretty unwieldy, imagine doing a PUT on cities/55 and have changed the list of companies associated with the city(or even a worker, in a company, in a city, all in a PUT on a city...)

If this doesn't make sense, let me know and I'll try to clarify. I've looked around and haven't found any answers regarding this exactly.

Comment: Foreign key constraints will actually cause issues if you try to delete something that another entry depends on. If you have ACME Co. in Chicago, and Chicago is a foreign key, and you try to delete Chicago, I believe SQL will throw a Foreign Key Constraint error.

Comment: Fair enough, I think that some SQL databases allow for cascaded deletes, where if you delete the "city" then all the companies will be deleted as well ( hence cascade). Even so, how is REST is normally meant to be implemented when you delete a parent entry?

Comment: I'm not sure there is a standard behavior here. Ignoring REST, since it's just the method for calling the function, the underlying issue is really regarding deleting data that is dependent on other data. Do companies cease to exist or matter if the city they are in is no longer cared about? Could they be re-associated at some point? Is the company used in other records? I have a system where, even when a user is deleted, they are just flagged "deleted" because of history associated with their accounts.

Comment: Aside from the delete question, and avoiding creating a chat thread in comments, I would assume, the question about returning companies with the city would be best answered by thinking about volume/number of COs and use. If I call a method ServiceArea/Cities, I expect city objects. If I call ServiceArea/Chicago/Companies, I expect company objects related to Chicago. This question might be more of a discussion topic, though.

Comment: I understand that the delete could be application-specific. I guess my problem isn't returning  cities* when someone gets companies/55/cities. My problem is that some places I've looked online ALSO return the nested resources when you GET a parent resource. And in those cases it doesn't make sense on how to handle updating/deleting.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at [restSQL](http://restsql.org) for inspiration. It can model resources as two level hierarchies. Write ops can be on the parents or children, but not both.